# using spark streaming from pyspark 2.4.4

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I have a spark 2.4.4 version set up in a k8s container. I am trying to write a simple hello world for using spark streams like this:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("pyspark-kafka").getOrCreate()
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 60)
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ['users-update'], {"metadata.broker.list":'pubsub-0.pubsub:9092,pubsub-1.pubsub:9092,pubsub-2.pubsub:9092'})
```

Note that pubsub-x.pubsub are kafka brokers that are visible to my container. (And a simple python program that directly uses the kafka-python client with the brokers and topic in my last line of pyspark code works just fine.)

I get this error message:

```
________________________________________________________________________________________________

  Spark Streaming's Kafka libraries not found in class path. Try one of the following.

  1. Include the Kafka library and its dependencies with in the
     spark-submit command as

     $ bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8:2.4.4 ...

  2. Download the JAR of the artifact from Maven Central http://search.maven.org/,
     Group Id = org.apache.spark, Artifact Id = spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly, Version = 2.4.4.
     Then, include the jar in the spark-submit command as

     $ bin/spark-submit --jars <spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly.jar> ...

________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

There are no version 2.4.4 kafka libraries anywhere on maven. https://search.maven.org/search?q=spark%20kafka shows that the last posted jars are with version 2.10 or 2.11.

I do have a spark-streaming_2.12-2.4.4.jar jar in my pyspark installation but it doesn't seem to have the right kafka classes.

Thanks for any pointers!
--Sridhar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark v2.4.4 is pre-built with scala v2.11. From spark download page:

> Note that, Spark is pre-built with Scala 2.11 except version 2.4.2, which is pre-built with Scala 2.12.

So, basically `2.10` and `2.11` are the scala version that spark is built with and you should download the spark-streaming-kafka jar which is built with the same version of scala in your case `2.11`.

I have checked in the jars folder in spark 2.4.4 and `spark-streaming_2.11-2.4.4.jar` jar is present there. So you should remove `spark-streaming_2.12-2.4.4.jar` if you have added this to the classpath externally or else you will get version mismatch.

You can download the `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly.jar` from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11/2.4.4)
And I think you also need to add `kafka-clients` jar from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/2.4.0) as well.

Comment: 2.4.4 also is built with Scala 2.12 - `spark-2.4.4-bin-without-hadoop-scala-2.12.tgz`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I installed the kafka python client by running `pip install kafka-python` After that, my little python snippet to connect to kafka works just fine. I installed `spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.4.jar` as well as `spark-streaming_2.11-2.4.4.jar` per your suggestion and made sure that no other streaming jars were present in jars. I still get the error, `An error occurred while calling o29.load.
:org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming...`

Comment: My updated pyspark code snippet that generates the error is:```from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("pyspark-kafka").getOrCreate()
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "pubsub-0.pubsub:9092,pubsub-1.pubsub:9092,pubsub-2.pubsub:9092") \
    .option("subscribe", "users-update") \
    .load()```

Comment: Can you show me your spark-submit command. And did you add kafka-clients jar to classpath which I mentioned in last line?

Comment: OK, I needed to have `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12/2.4.4/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-2.4.4.jar` in my spark jars as well. After that everything works perfectly. (@wypul, I was just running pyspark from a command line and entering python code line by line.) Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Sigh. More troubles. I reduced things down to downloading spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.4.jar , spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-2.4.4.jar and spark-streaming_2.11-2.4.4.jar into the pyspark/jars and removing spark-streaming_2.12-2.4.4.jar. Now, both with and without kafka-clients-2.4.0.jar, I am able to create the DataFrame in the code above fine. If I try to consume it with, `df.writeStream.foreach(lambda v: print(v)).start()` I get the error: `Missing required configuration "partition.assignment.strategy" which has no default value.`

Comment: @sridhar You have version mismatch in your jars. `2.11` and `2.12` in your jar names correspond to scala version. They should be same. `kafka-0-8` and `kafka-10` corresponds to kafka version. So if you have kafka 0.8 download `kafka-0-8` else `kafka-10` with correct scala version.

Comment: This is a messy set up of versions. If I use spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.4.jar I get: `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o29.load.
: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider could not be instantiated` and `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging$class` when creating the DataFrame. If I use spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-2.4.4.jar, I can create the data frame, but reading from it gives the partition.assignment.strategy error...

Comment: Winning configuration is: `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.11-2.4.4.jar` and `spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-2.4.4.jar` along with `spark-streaming_2.11-2.4.4.jar` and `kafka-clients-2.4.0.jar`. Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: @sridhar You're still mixing a 2.11 with 2.12. Please upgrade to all 2.12 dependencies

Comment: Apologies for the slow followup. I had hesitated to do that because it required rebuilding pyspark. But yes, I rebuilt it with 2.11 (and used spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.4.jar and spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.4.jar) and things are good. Please note that kafka-0-10 doesn't support python yet and so kafka-0-8 ends up being the best combination. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

> I do have a spark-streaming_2.12-2.4.4.jar jar in my pyspark installation but it doesn't seem to have the right kafka classes.

That's the base Streaming packages for Spark alone. Spark does not come with Kafka classes

Spark Streaming is deprecated in favor of Spark Structured Streaming

You want this package for Spark with Scala 2.12

```
'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.4'
```

And you'd start like this including options for bootstrap servers

```
df = spark.readStream().format("kafka")
```

Comment: You have provided the dependency for kafka 0.10 and I think as per the error kafka 0.8 dependency is required.

Comment: @wypul the error is only there because it is part of having `from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils` without the package available. The Structured Streaming package has API compatibility with the legacy streaming API